# Adaptec 7901 RAID 10 Degraded Drive - Cannot Rebuild

Tags: raid10, adaptec

I have a Tyan server with an onboard AIC-7901. One drive out of four in a RAID10 array is marked as degraded. I power down, pop out the offending drive, put in a good one, reboot and go into Adaptec Storage Manager. However, it errors when I try to make the new drive a hot spare to be used for rebuilding the array.

The error says: "Could not create hot-spare drive. Controller 1, channel 0, device ID 0.
Result codes:  RC:-5 API:2 IOCTL:0 SenseKey:3 ASC:49 ASCQ:1"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SCSI RAID controller had gone bad. A short while after posting this, the system would consistently BSOD. We ended up decommissioning the server.